# Перебор Json на PHP

Tags: php, json

есть данные:

```
{
  message:"Privet mir", 
  channels: [
    {
      id:"116", 
      logo:"3.png", 
      name:"\u0413\u043E\u0440\u043E\u0434", 
      city:"\u0411\u0435\u043B\u043E\u0440\u0435\u0446\u043A",
      ...
    }, 
    {
      id:"63", 
      logo:"2.png", 
      name:"\u0420\u0415\u041D \u0422\u0412", 
      city:"\u0411\u0435\u043B\u043E\u0440\u0435\u0446\u043A", 
      ...
    }
  ], 
  ...
}
```

Как извлечь все поля `name` и `city`?
код:

```
$str = $_POST['par']; //Приходят данные из js
$cart = json_decode( $str ); //Декодируем их в json
echo $cart->message . "<br>";  //Извлекаем message
```

Comment: так вы посмотрите на `channels` - это просто массив объектов, т.е. и работаете с ним как с массивом

Comment: echo $cart->channels[0]->name . "<br>";
echo $cart->channels[0]->city . "<br>"; таким образом  извлекаются  первое в списке name и city. А как извлечь все? подозреваю что foreach но что то я не могу понять как с ним работать, новичок в php

Comment: @Xanatos в мануале нет примеров использования? http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=684

Comment: foreach ( $cart as $value ) {} а где тут прописать  $cart->channels[0]?

Comment: Я явно что то делаю не так ибо как только я не пытался использовать foreach скрипт выдает  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 1):

Прошу обратить внимание на кавычки! `json_decode` требует валидного `json`, то есть

```
message:"Privet mir", // Не правильно

"message":"Privet mir", // Правильно
```

Итак:

```
<?
    $str = '{
      "message":"Privet mir",
      "channels": [
        {
          "id":"116",
          "logo":"3.png",
          "name":"\u0413\u043E\u0440\u043E\u0434",
          "city":"\u0411\u0435\u043B\u043E\u0440\u0435\u0446\u043A"
        },
        {
          "id":"63",
          "logo":"2.png",
          "name":"\u0420\u0415\u041D \u0422\u0412",
          "city":"\u0411\u0435\u043B\u043E\u0440\u0435\u0446\u043A"
        }
      ]
    }';

    $cart = json_decode( $str ); //Декодируем их в json

    foreach ($cart->channels as $channel) {
        echo $channel->name;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я получил примерно тоже самое, а если в channels [] будет еще вложен массив что то вроде channels:[{"id":"116", selectedDates:["11.01.2016", "21.01.2016"], cost:240}] как выглядит получение selectedDates?  $cart->channels->selectedDates?

Comment: при отдачи  echo $channel->name; обратно в js, alert выводит нужные данные но сам php выводит  nvalid argument supplied for foreach() как с этим боротся? или это из за невалидной json?

Comment: Кавычки! `[{"id":"116", "selectedDates":["11.01.2016", "21.01.2016"], "cost":240}]`

Comment: $cart = json_decode( $str ) в $str все в кавычках это json_decode их убирает чтоль? Oo

Comment: решено так if (is_array($cart->channels)){foreach...}